# How to avoid rendering a block in a base template - or: how to define a multiline block-like variable?

Tags: python, jinja2, templating-engine

I am rather new to jinja, so please excuse this potentially dumb question ...

I have a jinja macro sitting in a file named `lib.jinja` which looks as as follows

```
{% macro some_macro(some_content) %}
    <div class="some_class">{{ some_content }}</div>
{%- endmacro %}
```

I import it from another file named `content.htm`, which looks roughly as follows:

```
{% from "lib.jinja" import some_macro %}
{% block content %}
    Some content
{% endblock %}
{{ some_macro(self.some_macro(self.content())) }}
```

The rendered output looks as follows:

```
Some content
<div class="some_class">Some content</div>
```

Notice that the content appears twice, once rendered through/by the macro, another time - directly above - rendered like it was defined in the block named content in `content.htm`. I would love to avoid that the block is rendered twice - it is supposed to be fed into the macro and rendered through it only.

I appears that I can "work around" it by turning `content.htm` into a child template (by adding an `extends` tag at its top) of an empty base template.

Maybe I have a lack of understanding for the concepts here: A block is not a variable - I get that. If there is no `extends` tag, the template is treated as a base template, I assume. If there are no child templates or other directives, I guess the block is just rendered as-is and then, for a second time so to speak, picked up by the macro - correct?

How can I solve this in a sane manner, i.e. how could I handle this other than by extending an empty base template? Is there another type of block or variable that would fit my needs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just after I submitted this question, I finally found what I was looking for in the manual: [Block Assignments](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.10/templates/#block-assignments).

```
{% from "lib.jinja" import some_macro %}
{% set content %}
    Some content
{% endset %}
{{ some_macro(self.some_macro(content)) }}
```

The `set` and `endset` tags solve my problem.

Comment: I think you can `{% set content="Some content" %}`.

Comment: @Sraw Yep, but for multi-line content derived from other variables etc it's way nicer to use the option with an opening and a closing tag :)